# Can I modify primary key of partitioned table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a existing partitioned table . Primary key and partitioned column are different.Can I modify above primary key to add another column to it basically I want to make Composite primary key.Please let me know procedure if there exists a way to do it .

Comment: This is just way too broad. I have easily ten or twenty follow up questions. First being, why do you want to modify a functioning primary key? Shouldn't you just be looking at an additional index that includes the primary key column? And then, why is the table partitioned? Specifically, are you using partition switching? Is the primary key partitioned now? How big is the table? What's your down time tolerance? The short answer to your question is that yes, it's possible, but it could be between 2 and 2000 lines of code and we don't know enough to be of assistance.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and considering editing your question with additional detail.